# Direct forumula for a sequence that depends on a partial sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ where $$a_n=3n^{-1}(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(3+3kn^{-1}))$$ How would I go about finding a direct formula for each term so that I may analyze the sequence (for convergence etc). I have several problems of this form and I need a general way of converting a sequence that depends on a partial sum into a sequence that depends only on the one variable directly.

Thank you!

Comment: Faulhaber's formula.

Answer (score 2):

Writing for every summand a separate sigma sign.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}3+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}3kn^{-1}$$

Putting constants in front of the sigma signs

$$3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1+3n^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k$$

$$=3n+3n^{-1}\cdot \frac{(n-1)\cdot n}{2}$$

Multiplying both summands by $3\cdot n^{-1}=\frac3n$

$$9+9\cdot n^{-1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{2}$$

$$9\cdot \left(1+\frac12-\frac1{2n} \right)$$

$$a_n=9\cdot \left(\frac32-\frac1{2n} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

I have found $$\frac{3}{n}\left(\frac{9}{2}n-\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you Dr. Graubner. That seems to be the correct answer. How did you calculate this?

Comment: hm, you can expand and simplify your formula